# Use FindReplaceAction in custom view

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In my view I have a `StyledText` on which I want to open the default eclipse find/replace-dialog (The one that appears in the editor on Ctlr+F).
Therefore I want to instantiate and run the `FindReplaceAction` but my problem is that this action needs a `ResourceBundle` as a parameter and I have no idea what this is used for and where I can get it from...

I wonder whether this is actually the way to accomplish this functionality or if there is a way to register my view (that implements `IFindReplaceTarget`) globally in eclipse to recieve the Ctrl+F shortcut for opening the dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to participate in the standard Find/Replace code by having your view respond to a request for the `IFindReplaceTarget` in the `getAdapter` method of your main `ViewPart` class and setting up the find and replace action.

The adapter is something like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public <T> T getAdapter(Class<T> required) {

    if (IFindReplaceTarget.class.equals(required)) {
        return (T) ... your find replace target class
    }

    ... other adapters
}
```

Note: Older versions of Eclipse don't use Generics for this method.

Set up the `FindReplaceAction` with something like:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("my.package.Messages");
FindReplaceAction findReplaceAction = new FindReplaceAction(bundle, "find_replace_action_", this);
findReplaceAction.setActionDefinitionId(IWorkbenchCommandConstants.EDIT_FIND_AND_REPLACE);
IActionBars actionBars = getViewSite().getActionBars();
actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(ActionFactory.FIND.getId(), findReplaceAction);
```

The resource bundle needs a `Messages.properties` file with contents like:

```
find_replace_action_label=&Find/Replace...
find_replace_action_tooltip=Find/Replace
find_replace_action_image=
find_replace_action_description=Find/Replace
```

Comment: there is only a `public Object getAdapter(Class adapter)` method from the `WorkbenchPart` class and overwriting it with your code does not work. It doesn't even call this method when I invoke Ctrl+F in my View...

Comment: Sorry looks like I missed the need to set up the action. Added description of that to the answer. `getAdapter` was converted to use generics in Eclipse Neon earlier versions have the declaration you found.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I will test it shortly. Does this mean that This code would not work with Eclipse Neonas it now uses generic type arguments?

Comment: No, the generic getAdapter is compatible with the older getAdapter.